# WFC Rest Service with ASP.NET Compatibility mode - How to set up large POST Requests?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, iis, post

Good Morning community, I hope you can help me with an issue I'm facing right now.
I have a WFC REST Service using ASP.NET Compatibility mode (so i can ignore the .svc endpoint in the url).
My REST Service is receiving XML and returning XML as well. when testing with different POST Request I get an error 400 for the POST. my XML test files between 100 Kb and 200 Kb.

This is my Web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I saw various posts on Internet regarding allowing more size for the POST, but I don't know how to do it with ASP.NET Compatibility.

Someone can help me to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Definetly, this is a silly question by me... I just figured out that We can configure the **`standardEnpoint`** tag from the **`webHttpEndpoint`** section.

In this case I modify to allow a bigger Message size than 64 Kb.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="MAX_SIZE" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Where **`MAX_SIZE`** is the size of bytes you want to allow in the application.